# Simple python and need explanation

Tags: python-3.x

```
m = 0
for x in range (4,6):
   for y in range (2,4):
      m = m + x + y
print (m)
```

ANSWER: 28

not sure how this is? Excluding the last number in the range, I thought it should be 14. I add it up on paper and cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That loop is equivalent to:

```
m = 4+2 + 4+3 + 5+2 + 5+3
```

And, that sum is 28.

(In the outer loop, `x` takes on the values `4` and `5`.  In the inner loop, `y` takes on values `2` and `3`.)